# How can we fill linear gradient color in google slide by api?

Tags: google-slides-api

Below example of normal fill color.

```
$requests[] = new \Google_Service_Slides_Request(array(
                      'updateShapeProperties' => array(
                        'objectId' => "elementID",
                        'fields' => "shapeBackgroundFill.solidFill.color",
                          'shapeProperties' => array(
                            'shapeBackgroundFill' =>  array(
                              'solidFill' => array(
                                'color' => array(
                                  'rgbColor' => array(
                                    'red' => "RGBCODE_0",
                                    'green' => "RGBCODE_1",
                                    'blue' => "RGBCODE_2"
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    );
```

I want to set color like below in google slide by GOOGLE API.

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,0.1), rgba(245,185,188,1));
```

Above code for HTML & CSS.

Answer (score 2):

As you can withdraw the [Slides API documentation](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/shapes#Page.ShapeBackgroundFill), the only currently present interfaces for `ShapeBackgroundFill` are `propertyState` and `solidFill`.

### Gradient fill is unfortunately not an option.

Indeed, even from the user interface it is [not possible](https://support.google.com/docs/forum/AAAABuH1jm0HOoqsLoXTfE/?hl=en&gpf=%23!msg%2Fdocs%2FHOoqsLoXTfE%2FGkQDx-g5AAAJ&msgid=GkQDx-g5AAAJ) to implement a custom gradient as shape background fill.

> If it is of any help: You can implement a [ThemeColor](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/other#Page.ThemeColorType).

If this does not solve your issue, you can file a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) at [Google Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) and hope that the feature will be implemented in the future.